# Object necessary for warmstarting database cannot be altered ORACLE

Tags: oracle, performance, index, alter-table, index-rebuild

I have this error when I want to rebuild system index :

```
00701. 00000 -  "object necessary for warmstarting database cannot be altered"
*Cause:    Attempt to alter or drop a database object (table, cluster, or
           index) which are needed for warmstarting the database.
*Action:   None.
```

the command for rebuild :

```
ALTER INDEX I_IND1 REBUILD ONLINE TABLESPACE SYSTEM;
```

I tried also :

```
alter index  I_IND1 rebuild;
```

but the same message.
Please any help .

Comment: What is the original problem that you tried solving with this?

Comment: @BalazsPapp block that has corruption :(

Comment: For that you will most likely need to restore from RMAN backup or possibly use the DBMS_REPAIR package. What method are you attempting to use to fix the problem?

Comment: @pmdba actually I didn't have a backup unfortunately and when I use the DBMS_REPAIR ,It make the same error :(

Comment: Time to raise a ticket with Oracle support. You shouldn't be doing DDL against system objects unless instructed to do so by them.

Comment: @AndrewSayer thanks I will open SR :) thanks all :)